# Python SQL insert statement only inserts part of the records

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, insert

I am trying to figure out why my SQL-insert command is running into issues. I am trying to insert ~5k records into a table on a daily basis and have designed a for-loop to create a SQL-command that runs an INSERT INTO for each of these records.

I use the code below that generates one massive string that is then run in the SQL environment.

When I run this code I end up with irratic amounts of records inserted (can be 300, 1000 or 600). Strangely enough, if I copy the total_sql string into SQL server directly and run it, it creates all records. So I believe there is an issue with running this SQL-code remotely.

Has anyone had a similar issue like this before? I initially thought it was related to the length of the string, but that would not explain why the amount of records changes each time I run it so I'm running out of ideas.. Thanks!

```
total_sql = ''
n= 0
for i in range(Mydata.shape[0]):
    current_line = '''INSERT INTO TableName (ColumnName)
    VALUES
    (''' + My_data[i] "') "
    total_sql = total_sql + current_line
    n+=1

cursor.execute(total_sql)
```

FYI, I originally had a system that ran an insert for each individual row, but this proved to be slow and more likely to result in server communication time-outs.

Comment: You create a brand new `current_line` value each time through the loop, overwriting any previous one each time, so only the last value exists by the time you get to your `cursor.execute()`.

Comment: The total_sql string includes all records stuck together, so that includes all records (+ I'm seeing hundreds of records, so the overwriting cannot be the issue right?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using pandas instead?

You only need to transfer in to a dataframe first. Which format is it now?

```
import pandas as pd

df.to_sql('TABLE NAME',connection, if_exists = 'append',index=False)
```

Where df is your data transformed into a dataframe.

Comment: Thanks, having a look at this now.

Still strange that this other insert doesn't work though.. 

Also built a system using cursor.executemany(), but that is still very slow so hope to get something like this running.